# Testing private method calls

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine

Take this class:

```
public class LoginPresenter
{
    private ILoginView view;
    private APIWrapper api;
    (...)
    public virtual IEnumerator Login(string email, string password)
    {
        return api.Login(email, password, OnSuccess, OnError);
    }

    private void OnError(HttpError error)
    {
        switch (error.statusCode)
        {
            case 0:
                view.ShowMessage("Check your Internet Connection");
                break;
            default:
                view.ShowMessage("Invalid Credentials");
                break;
        }
    }
    (...)
}
```

I need to write a test for when Login fails, but I'm not sure about the right way to do it. This is how I was asked to do it:

```
public class LoginPresenterTests
{
    private LoginPresenter presenter;
    private ILoginView view;
    (...)
    [Test]
    public void _03_Test_LoginOnError()
    {
        //Arrange
        Dictionary<int, string> statusCodeMessages = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            {0, "Check your Internet Connection"},
            {401, "Invalid Credentials"}
        };

        //Act
        foreach (var statusCodeMessage in statusCodeMessages)
        {
            object[] args = { new HttpError(statusCodeMessage.Key, "", "") };
            ReflectionUtils.Invoke(presenter, "OnError", args);
            
            //Assert
            view.Received().ShowMessage(statusCodeMessage.Value);
        }
    }
    (...)
}
```

But it seems **so wrong** to me. This is nothing but a mirror of the original function. A single change to the message string would break the test. Is this really what testing is about? Shouldn't I just be checking whether `OnError` is called if login fails, nothing more?

Then again, given that `OnError` is a callback *and* a private method, I don't know how to check if it was called...

Comment: generally you shouldn't test for private members, as those are implementaion-details that may change. Public members on the other hand must not change.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I'm not the boss. In his opinion, OnError contains logic, therefore it must be tested; and I oblige. But I still want to know the right way of doing things. So the question stands: How to properly test the case when Login fails?

Comment: well, I suppose you shouldn't test if the delegate is called within your class, because it's not the repsonibility of that class to call the delegate. This is what your `APIWrapper`-class  is about, isn't it?

Comment: Mock the injected dependencies to behave as expected when the subject under test is invoked. From there assert the expected behavior. This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Don't apply white-collar business-style coding to _games._  They are a distraction from the problem at hand.

Comment: If you really need to you could use the attribute [`[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo(...)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute) and thereby at least expose `internal` types and members to the test assembly

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it is generally not considered good practice to invoke private methods using reflection when testing.

For this answer, I will assume you are writing a unit test for LoginPresenter, and so you should not be concerned with the behaviour of ApiWrapper or the View. The approach would be different if you were writing an integration test.

I assume the ApiWrapper class is part of your codebase? (Sorry I'm not familiar with Unity). If so, you could create an interface for ApiWrapper, then have LoginPresenter reference the interface instead of the concrete class. The following technique may also be possible without the interface, as long as the Login method is virtual.

You're missing the part of the code where the view and api are instantiated or, more likely, injected into the presenter via the constructor. Ideally, the class looks like this:

```
public class LoginPresenter
{
    private ILoginView view;
    private IAPIWrapper api;

    public LoginPresenter(ILoginView view, IAPIWrapper api)
    {
         this.api = api;
         this.view = view;
    }

    public virtual IEnumerator Login(string email, string password)
    {
        return api.Login(email, password, OnSuccess, OnError);
    }

    // etc
```

Next, in your test, you can use a mocking framework (such as NSubstitute) to pass a mock of your api and view into the LoginPresenter. Then, you mock the api.Login method, and tell it to call its fourth argument (OnError) when it executes. How exactly you do this will depend on your mocking framework.

Finally, you assert that the view received the ShowMessage call, in the same way as you are doing already.